# Add global properties to Vue 3 using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to add a global property to a Vue 3 application like suggested [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/10-good-practices-building-maintaining-large-vuejs-projects#6usedconfigtoaccessyourenvironmentvariablesespeciallyusefulintemplates)

The prototype approach does not work with TypeScript.

I found an example that I converted into this code as config.d.ts

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import base from '@/config/config.json'
import dev from '@/config/config.dev.json'
import prod from '@/config/config.prod.json'

let config
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config = Object.freeze(Object.assign(base, prod))
} else {
  config = Object.freeze(Object.assign(base, dev))
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $config: config
  }
}
```

I want to load some local configuration files with dev or prod scope. The scoped files will not be checked into GIT repository.

The main.ts now looks like this...

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Config from '@/plugins/config.d.ts'

Vue.use(Config)
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

The problem:

```
ERROR in src/main.ts:6:5
TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof import("d:/Martin/Entwicklung/2020/STA-Electron/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")'.
    4 | import Config from '@/plugins/config.d.ts'
    5 |
  > 6 | Vue.use(Config)
      |     ^^^
    7 | createApp(App).mount('#app')
    8 |
```

What I ideally want to achieve is a global `config` or `$config` property that can be used in the setup method of Vue 3

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {},
  setup(props, context) {
    const elem = ref(context.$config.prop1)
    const doSth = () => {
      console.log('Config', context.$config)
    }
    return {doSth, elem}
  },
})
```

How can I fix this?

### Update

After the answer from danielv so new plugin looks this

```js
import {App} from 'vue'

export interface ConfigOptions {
  base: any
  dev: any
  prod: any
}

export default {
  install: (app: App, options: ConfigOptions) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$config =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, options.base, options.prod))
        : Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, options.base, options.dev))
  },
}
```

The main.ts changed also into this

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import ConfigPlugin from '@/plugins/config'
import base from '@/config/config.json'
import dev from '@/config/config.dev.json'
import prod from '@/config/config.prod.json'

createApp(App).use(ConfigPlugin, {base, dev, prod}).mount('#app')
```

This simple plugin can be used in the template

```html
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <p>{{ $config.prop1 }}</p>
</template>
```

IntelliJ complains about unknown variable prop1, but it works.

I searched a lot but found no way to insert my $config into the setup method that is used with the composition api.

Comment: "I searched a lot but found no way to insert my $config into the setup method that is used with the composition api."
- I missed this part of the conversation, this ends up being a bit of a deal breaker as I now have a global variable which I can use everywhere except in setup logic, for this reason, provide-inject approach is potentially better

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can augment the `@vue/runtime-core` TypeScript module in your application:

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $config: Record<string, unknown>;
  }
}

export {}  // Important! See note.
```

Here is a documentation: [ComponentCustomProperties](https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#componentcustomproperties)

**Important note:** TS module augmentation works correctly **only** when it is placed in the [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
> top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module. Conversely, a
> file without any top-level `import` or `export` declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

Therefore the file must contain at least one top-level `import` or `export` statement, even if empty one (as in the example above) - [Type Augmentation Placement](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#type-augmentation-placement)

Comment: Do not forget to add `import Vue from 'vue'` before augmenting the module as defined in the linked documentation.

Comment: Soooo... this has never worked for me, Vue 2 or 3. At least Vetur doesn't like it. I'm developing a local dependency. Anyone got this to work in the same context as me?

Comment: the compiler does not like this a bit ` Module '"../../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'defineComponent'.` ??

Comment: to augment the `globalProperties` you need on import first `import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue';` otherwise the compiler will complain about it

Comment: I have the same issue as @Exlord. Once I save my typings in `src/typings/index.d.ts` in a Vite based Vue project (with ts), it seems like this overrides the `@vue/runtime-core` typings instead of augmenting them. Every time I define a component using defineComponent, I get this TS error saying `Module '"../../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'defineComponent'.` too. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I want to add Vue 3 support to OneSignal's Vue plugin but it seems that the module declaration isn't working correctly when testing in an example app. See https://github.com/OneSignal/onesignal-vue/tree/vue3-temp which includes the example app as well. I am testing this in VSCode. The type definitions simply never appear. If anyone has any idea or can help me fix it, we can give you credit as a plugin collaborator. The plugin has a top-level export so it should be considered a module. I've compared this with other Vue plugins and can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: see also this [webstorm bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59818/Vue-custom-global-properties-added-by-augmenting-vue-are-not-resolved) that requires augmenting one or both of `vue` and `@vue/runtime-core` in order for completions to work in your vue3 templates

Comment: @djeikyb I was going to comment about webstorm complaining that. I saw yours after expanding remaning comments :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 3, you call the `use` method on the instance of your app, it's not a method on the Vue var.

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
app.use(config)
```

Also, you need to write your plugin to conform to what Vue 3 expects (an object with `install` method).

Check out [Vue 3 guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html) on writing and using plugins, it describe a very similar use case to yours.

By the way, `*.d.ts` files are intended to be used as pure declaration files to declare types, usually as a supplement to otherwise untyped modules (e.g. typing existing js code). You generally don't need to write `*.d.ts` files yourself when writing Typescript code (declarations can be auto generated by the tsc compiler).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Can you please go a little more into detail? I Updated the question.

Comment: Coming from pure TS projects: I am wonder about your statement "You generally don't need to write *.d.ts files". How do you declare a type which is used a hundred times across your project? We have a global.d.ts file and put it there. Afaik it's a common use case.

Comment: Yes, it is a common practice and it's certainly valid one but generally, typescript discourages global types in favor of scoped and namespaced types. You can use d.ts files but the main purpose of those is to provide typing when they're otherwise unavailable (eg. when using untyped javascript) and you can also declare global types in *.ts files, if you must. It's not wrong, just that usually you don't necessarily need or want them.

Comment: If you are injecting data from one component to another it probably is necessary to use a custom type so it isn't so confusing and to catch errors.